# Recovering data from dead Sandisk Ultrafit

Tags: hard-drive, usb

So- that "always back up everything lesson"? I thought I learned it years ago, turns out I didnt.

I was storing my compsci midterm project (which is due tomorrow) on a thumdrive to take it to and from school, when last night it went dead. Utterly dead. After several hours of trying to get to to connect, even briefly, so I can take a disk image, I've come crawling to Superuser in last hope.

What I know:

A couple months ago, the cap fell off the thumbdrive. That's fine, I thought I can snap it back together and keep using it. It'd come off from time to time, but I never thought it an issue. This time, however, it came apart, and when I put it back together the red light on the top didnt light up at all. The computer doesnt even detect anything's plugged into the USB port.

If I wiggle it back and forth without the case on or anything, I can get the light to flicker, very briefly, at the top, and once even got as far as getting the computer to say "USB device malfunctioned", which is the farthest I have gotten.

I figure this means the contacts are broken or scratched? I'm not sure.

Here are some pictures of the broken drive:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcMRV.jpg

What troubleshooting steps can I take in the next 12 hours? I've tried canned air, wiggling it, testing different computers and usb ports, with the casing, without it, etc.

Thanks, sincerely, for any help you can give me not failing my midterm.

**Edit 1:** Looking at USB spec diagrams, USB 2.0 and 3.0 use different sets of connections? I'll try to find something with a USB 2 port and see if that might work.

**Edit 2:** Found a USB 2.0 hub- no luck, doesnt even flicker in this one.

**Edit 3:** A lot of cases like this seem to be solder issues, but I cant see any solder thanks to how this is constructed. Would there be any safe way to reflow the disk?

**Edit 4:** Just spent a very long time wiggling it around, hoping to find the perfect position. I can get windows to make the detected usb device noise, the red light flickers very briefly, and then it tells me USB device malfunctioned.
If it wasnt solid plastic I'd consider reflowing it with a heat gun- but- ugh.

**Edit 5:** This thread (http://www.hackerthreads.org/Topic-43611) seems to imply there might be a route to drag the data off with a XD card reader, too? This is miserable.

**Edit 6:** Got out a magnifying glass, found the solder pads. They look fine to my utterly untrained eye- huh. Here's some pictures: (Actually, cant post more then 2 links, will put in comments)

**Edit 7:** Okay, so after extensive investigation, the light flickers once, as it makes contact, then goes out. It flickers again the moment it makes contact, then stops again. So it turns on for a brief second any time contact is made. It also gets hot if left in the port.

**Edit 8:** Tried freeze spray I borrowed from a friend, as I heard that might help. No luck there either.

Comment: Closer look: http://imgur.com/a/TCUFM

Comment: Thumb drives are powered by an in-build capacitor, which I believe when that dies the data is lost, unlike a hard drive which stores data on a physical disk.

Comment: @Daedric I thought they used non-volatile NAND?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can try DIY wise is use hot air station to remove the blue part and solder a USB 2 connector to the drive. That's your only shot at fixing this within next few hours.

If that does not work then there's not a lot you can do other than take it to a data recovery specialist who can try dumping the NAND while bypassing the controller.

For this

- the blue connector needs removed using a hot air station
- in most cases we need to scrape off a thin layer to expose pins
- we can solder wires to required to access the NAND chip using NAND protocol.

[image]

Then determine pins we need to wire to NAND reader

[image]

Most common cause is 'bad NAND' memory. It may be even so your connector issues are a different issue than the one causing the UFD to fail now. Once we 'dumped' the NAND we need to assemble a logical image using something like Flash Extractor software.

[image]

*If* it's purely a connector issue, soldering a USB 2 connector should solve it.

If it gets hot like you say we might be dealing with a short. You can check out the few SMD components on there, if it's internal there's not a lot you can do. You can again use the freeze spray to try pinpoint what exactly gets hot.